# reference a class type within a different class

Tags: swift, swift3

I am wondering how to reference a class type within another class for instance (a rough Sketch not a true example) I have two classes:

```
class Class1: UIViewController {
     var a = self
}
class Class2: SKScene {
     //How do I get a to equal the same thing as it equals in class 1?
     var a = //??????????
}
```

How can I get the same a value in Class2 as in class 1. essentially references class2's self value in another class. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y issue. Why isn't *Class2* a subclass of *Class1*?

Comment: In reality, Class 1 is a view controller sorry I will change my question.

Comment: @dfd I have never worked with subclasses before but if they are possible to use in my situation, that would be great. Some more information is that Class 1 actually presents class 2.

Comment: There's a few ways to do it, depending on the "flow" of your app. I haven't worked with SpriteKit for 2 years now, but how are these two classes "connected"? Is the VC also controlling things in the Scene? Is there a segue from one to the other? Is one instantiating the other? Also, are they in the same file, project, etc.? These are important to give you a good answer. ADDED: You *are* subclassing - Class1 is a subclass of UIViewController and Class2 is a subclass of SKScene.

Comment: It seems you want to create a delegate instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much detail you have provided in question, based on that i can give you this solution:

```
 class Class1: UIViewController {
             static let sharedInstance : Class1= {
               let instance = Class1()
              return instance
          }()
     }

    class Class2: SKScene {
         var a = Class1.sharedInstance 
    }
```

Comment: evil evil singletons. Probably the answer is to include `Class2` as the model object inside `Class1` and connect `Class1` as the delegate of `Class2`. Sharing data from UI to data model? That's evil architecture.

Comment: Actually this is not clearly specified in the question how these two classes are related.